# Which job title to use?

Tags: title

I currently work at a large company and because of major re-org few months ago I have 3 different job title:

- **Job Offer:** X Consultant
- **From Official HR Record:** Consultant, X
- **From Org. Chart:** X Analyst

This may sound silly but which title should I be using on resume? I'm inclined to use 'Consultant' but within various groups 'Analyst' seem to be used more often.

Comment: If someone calls to verify your employment, what will HR tell them?

Answer (score 4):

Probably doesn't matter what title you use, because:

1. The titles are close enough in similarity that they are more or less recognizable as pertaining to the same position in the eyes of the people within your organization. These titles are practically a "distinction without a difference".
2. None of these titles mean anything to anyone who reads your resume unless you describe what you managed to get done in that position that's music to their ears.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a secret: nobody really cares what your job title is. As Vietnhi's already mentioned, what matters is what you do in your role. The only bits where your current title has value:

1. Getting past the initial check when you're applying for a new role. In this case, make sure whatever title is on your resume is whatever you think has the best chance of getting whoever's doing the initial resume scan to read the rest of it - and crucially, this may vary depending on the role you're applying for.
2. Ensuring that you pass any background checks. Again as noted by Vietnhi, the difference between "consultant" and "analyst" is pretty small, but if you're really worried about it you can always do something like "X Analyst (official title: X Consultant)".

Comment: In my workplace, the difference between an Analyst and Consultant was actually relatively big, with a Consultant being one tier higher in the hierarchy. Big enough to cause some confusion in OP's case. But I agree, it all depends on the company, so you shouldn't read too much into titles.