# What job title should I list on my Resume when working on AI and Backend Projects?

Tags: job-search, resume, title

I have implemented few Deep learning models (computer vision) and deployed them in Django. I also have developed a ML project using Django ORM. Now I have experience in ML, in computer vision and with Django.

What should be my title in the resume? Is `Artificial Intelligence & Backend Engineer` fine?

Comment: Why are you coming up with a title? Didn't your company give you some "official" title when you were hired and in your contract?

Comment: In my Organization we are having a roles like Systems Engineer which is not an effective way to describe my role.

Comment: I see. I included an answer for you to consider. Welcome to The Workplace BTW :) feel free to take the [tour] and read the [help/dont-ask] to start to familiarize yourself with this Stack. Cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which job title to use?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40735/which-job-title-to-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should be my title in resume?

As you can see, titles are not the best way to convey or describe your role in a job.

Thus, in your resume you should list the exact title you have assigned, but in order to explain what that role means, you should give a **concise description of the actual tasks and roles you play on that job.**

In other words, the description of the things you do matter more than the title you have assigned (titles vary greatly between companies).

Thus, I would suggest you go with something like this, adjusting it to your preferences:

> Systems Engineer at Acme, Inc. (2017- Present): In charge of designing, implementing, and evaluating several Computer Vision and Machine Learning projects, using tools and libraries like OpenCV, Django, Scikit, and Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of recruiting developers, the title matters very little. The most important are:

1. - What you have already accomplished allows the recruiter to know your experiences
2. - What are the tools with which you feel good so that you will not be demotivated from the start
3. Your passion for the project on which you are going to work
4. - Your state of mind